# String Contains in lambda reflections Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda, .net-core

I'm trying to use [this example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f8fe1fd-d620-4103-aba3-a57281e3861a/lambda-reflection?forum=csharpgeneral) to dinamically pass table field names to queries and avoid repeating frequent query operations for each table field.

The code contained in the example and edited as I need is the following:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> GreatherThan<T>(string field, string value)
{
    ParameterExpression B = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(B, field),
            Expression.Constant(value)),
        B);
}
```

It works fine with numeric fields, as it has under `Expression` every operation that I need for a numeric field (equal, not equal, greater/less than, etc...).

**But it seems there is no operation for strings, as `Contains` or similar.** (*Except `Equal` and `NotEqual`, of course.*)

How can I achieve something like the following? (which by now is syntactically wrong but it's for example purpose)

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> Contains<T>(string field, string value)
{
    ParameterExpression B = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Contains(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(B, field),
            Expression.Constant(value)),
        B);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the method on the string object:

```
    var s = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");
    var term = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "term");


    var contains = Expression.Call(s, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), term);

    Func<string, string, bool> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string,string,bool>>(contains, s, term).Compile();


    Console.WriteLine(lambda("test", "e")); //True
```